# Lenovo 14ARE05 Touchpad/trackpad not working Ubuntu 22.04 v 5.15

Tags: boot, dual-boot, touchpad

First off totally new to Ubuntu / Linux so don't roast me.

(I'm dual booting with windows, and that's probably my issue) But I've turned off secure boot in UEFI, and I've tried editing grub the bevy of "pci=nocrs quiet splash" etc, and all I've been able to accomplish is disabling my wifi.

I get this error in the system log-
mtd device must be supplied(device name is empty)"pci=nocrs quiet splash"

Do I have to find some drivers for this touchpad???

Comment: We don't know what is "this touchpad". May be it is not supported yet.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, it's model number MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140, I've tried most of this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371681/touchpad-only-works-on-certain-reboot-conditions-cant-be-bound-to-driver-ideap

Comment: Also this info is important https://forum.manjaro.org/t/lenovo-ideapad-flex-5-14are05-touchpad-not-working-expect-with-workaround/93580